# Web scraping javascript with htmlunit - "You are currently browsing with JavaScript turned off"

Tags: javascript, java, web-scraping, htmlunit

I'm trying to scrape [this page](https://doaj.org/search?source=%7B%22query%22%3A%7B%22filtered%22%3A%7B%22filter%22%3A%7B%22bool%22%3A%7B%22must%22%3A%5B%7B%22term%22%3A%7B%22index.classification.exact%22%3A%22Biology%20(General)%22%7D%7D%5D%7D%7D%2C%22query%22%3A%7B%22match_all%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%7D%7D%2C%22sort%22%3A%5B%7B%22created_date%22%3A%7B%22order%22%3A%22desc%22%7D%7D%5D%7D) with HtmlUnit. In the Xml, it says "You are currently browsing with JavaScript turned off which means you can't use our search functionality." I've been able to scrape it before using Python and Selenium, but I haven't been able to get it to work with Java and

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.SilentCssErrorHandler;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;

public class WebScraper {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        try {
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
            webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(2000);
            webClient.setCssErrorHandler(new SilentCssErrorHandler());
            HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://doaj.org/search?source=%7B%22query%22%3A%7B%22filtered%22%3A%7B%22filter%22%3A%7B%22bool%22%3A%7B%22must%22%3A%5B%7B%22term%22%3A%7B%22index.classification.exact%22%3A%22Biology%20(General)%22%7D%7D%5D%7D%7D%2C%22query%22%3A%7B%22match_all%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%7D%7D%2C%22sort%22%3A%5B%7B%22created_date%22%3A%7B%22order%22%3A%22desc%22%7D%7D%5D%7D");
            System.out.println(page.asXml());

            webClient.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You understand  the technical difference between the two?

Comment: No, I'll look into it. If you have any insights to share, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Selenium drives a full browser running aside your test code(which has Javascript).  htmlunit is a simple browser implemented in Java which does not have Javascript.

Comment: Thanks very much! I switched to Selenium and it's working now.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen - htmlunit _does_ have some [level of support](https://htmlunit.sourceforge.io/javascript.html#:~:text=Core%20language%20support%20for%20JavaScript,such%20as%20Document%20or%20Navigator.) for JavaScript (albeit not as complete as a full browser implementation). They describe their support as "fairly good" [here](https://htmlunit.sourceforge.io/) for what it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the content of the web page are rendered by javascript started async. You have to wait a bit to get the content....

```
String url = "https://doaj.org/search?source=%7B%22query%22%3A%7B%22filtered%22%3A%7B%22filter%22%3A%7B%22bool%22%3A%7B%22must%22%3A%5B%7B%22term%22%3A%7B%22index.classification.exact%22%3A%22Biology%20(General)%22%7D%7D%5D%7D%7D%2C%22query%22%3A%7B%22match_all%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%7D%7D%2C%22sort%22%3A%5B%7B%22created_date%22%3A%7B%22order%22%3A%22desc%22%7D%7D%5D%7D";

try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX)) {
    // js is enabled by default
    webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(1_000);

    HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(url);
    webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10_000);

    System.out.println(page.asText());
}
```

Works here with version 2.42.0-SNAPSHOT but should work also with the 2.41.0 release.