# HtmlUnit - Error during JavaScript execution

Tags: java, web-scraping, htmlunit

I want to scrape flashScore.com webpage which is fully rendered during visit in Javascript. I Use HtmlUnit for rendering and have now the first problem already and cant scrape the page at all.

```
@PostMapping("/startScraping")
public ResponseEntity<FlashScraper> startScraping(@NonNull @RequestBody FlashScraper flashScraper) throws FailingHttpStatusCodeException, MalformedURLException, IOException {
    logger.info("startScraping request incoming");
    logger.info("Call URL: " + flashScraper.getScrapeUrl());
    
    
    final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.BEST_SUPPORTED);
    
    HtmlPage scrapePage = webClient.getPage(flashScraper.getScrapeUrl());
    webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(3000);
    
    System.out.println(scrapePage.getByXPath("//*[@id=\"g_25_rwPxTVj1\"]"));
    
    return new ResponseEntity(flashScraper, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

After send a POST request to startScraping endpoint, i got following exception

```
2021-07-04 14:43:57.569  WARN 14872 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.g.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler      : CSS warning: 'https://www.flashscore.com/res/_fs/build/livetableresponsive.2da0223.css' [1:8910] Ignoring the whole rule.
2021-07-04 14:43:58.035  WARN 14872 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.g.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl   : Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
2021-07-04 14:43:58.175 ERROR 14872 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.g.h.j.DefaultJavaScriptErrorListener   : Error during JavaScript execution com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot find function entries in object function Object() { [native code] }. (script in https://www.flashscore.com/unsupported/ from (31, 9) to (53, 10)#35) 
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:949) ~[htmlunit-2.50.0.jar:2.50.0]
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:598) ~[htmlunit-core-js-2.50.0.jar:na] 
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:487) ~[htmlunit-core-js-2.50.0.jar:na]
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.callSecured(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:353) ~[htmlunit-2.50.0.jar:2.50.0]
```

Do you have any doubt where the problem is?

Thx
T.

Comment: java!=javascript

Answer (score 0):

Please set the options before getting the page

```
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.BEST_SUPPORTED);
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);

HtmlPage scrapePage = webClient.getPage(flashScraper.getScrapeUrl());
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(3000);
```

I guess the error will still be there but because you set setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false) the execution will no longer stop on the error.

Comment: Hello RBRi, thanks for the hint - i've tried but it seems i got still errors. The Webpage (flashscore.com) detect, that HtmlUnit is not a real browser and send me to this page: https://www.flashscore.com/unsupported/

Comment: Ok, do you use the latest version?
Please open a github issue and i will try to have a deeper look at this.

Comment: Hello RBRi, i changed Dependency to 2.51.0 now and i dont see the Exception anymore.

But still, i am on the flashscore.com/unsupported page - so the JS is not handled properly?!

Answer (score 0):

After change the sequence of the parameters i still got following error - also the HtmlUnit Browser is forwarded to flashscore.com/unsupported

```
2021-07-06 08:46:15.869  WARN 14464 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.g.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler      : CSS warning: 'https://www.flashscore.com/res/_fs/build/livetableresponsive.2da0223.css' [1:8910] Ignoring the whole rule.
2021-07-06 08:46:16.638  WARN 14464 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.g.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl   : Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
2021-07-06 08:46:16.783 ERROR 14464 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.g.h.j.DefaultJavaScriptErrorListener   : Error during JavaScript execution

com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot find function entries in object function Object() { [native code] }. (script in https://www.flashscore.com/unsupported/ from (31, 9) to (53, 10)#35)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:949) ~[htmlunit-2.50.0.jar:2.50.0]
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:598) ~[htmlunit-core-js-2.50.0.jar:na]
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:487) ~[htmlunit-core-js-2.50.0.jar:na]
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.callSecured(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:353) ~[htmlunit-2.50.0.jar:2.50.0]
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:829) ~[htmlunit-2.50.0.jar:2.50.0]
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:805) ~[htmlunit-2.50.0.jar:2.50.0]
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:796) ~[htmlunit-2.50.0.jar:2.50.0]
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScript(HtmlPage.java:942) ~[htmlunit-2.50.0.jar:2.50.0]
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.ScriptElementSupport.executeInlineScriptIfNeeded(ScriptElementSupport.java:378) ~[htmlunit-2.50.0.jar:2.50.0]
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.ScriptElementSupport.executeScriptIfNeeded(ScriptElementSupport.java:230) ~[htmlunit-2.50.0.jar:2.50.0]
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.ScriptElementSupport$1.execute(ScriptElementSupport.java:120) ~[htmlunit-2.50.0.jar:2.50.0]
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.ScriptElementSupport.onAllChildrenAddedToPage(ScriptElementSupport.java:143) ~[htmlunit-2.50.0.jar:2.50.0]
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.onAllChildrenAddedToPage(HtmlScript.java:191) ~[htmlunit-2.50.0.jar:2.50.0]
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.parser.neko.HtmlUnitNekoDOMBuilder.endElement(HtmlUnitNekoDOMBuilder.java:551) ~[htmlunit-2.50.0.jar:2.50.0]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.12.0.jar:na]
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.parser.neko.HtmlUnitNekoDOMBuilder.endElement(HtmlUnitNekoDOMBuilder.java:503) ~[htmlunit-2.50.0.jar:2.50.0]
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLTagBalancer.callEndElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1216) ~[neko-htmlunit-2.50.0.jar:2.50.0]
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLTagBalancer.endElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1156) ~[neko-htmlunit-2.50.0.jar:2.50.0]
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.filters.DefaultFilter.endElement(DefaultFilter.java:219) ~[neko-htmlunit-2.50.0.jar:2.50.0]
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.filters.NamespaceBinder.endElement(NamespaceBinder.java:312) ~[neko-htmlunit-2.50.0.jar:2.50.0]
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scanEndElement(HTMLScanner.java:3189) ~[neko-htmlunit-2.50.0.jar:2.50.0]
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scan(HTMLScanner.java:2114) ~[neko-htmlunit-2.50.0.jar:2.50.0]
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner.scanDocument(HTMLScanner.java:937) ~[neko-htmlunit-2.50.0.jar:2.50.0]
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:443) ~[neko-htmlunit-2.50.0.jar:2.50.0]
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:394) ~[neko-htmlunit-2.50.0.jar:2.50.0]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.12.0.jar:na]
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.parser.neko.HtmlUnitNekoDOMBuilder.parse(HtmlUnitNekoDOMBuilder.java:751) ~[htmlunit-2.50.0.jar:2.50.0]
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.parser.neko.HtmlUnitNekoHtmlParser.parse(HtmlUnitNekoHtmlParser.java:208) ~[htmlunit-2.50.0.jar:2.50.0]
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createHtmlPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:296) ~[htmlunit-2.50.0.jar:2.50.0]
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:216) ~[htmlunit-2.50.0.jar:2.50.0]
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:682) ~[htmlunit-2.50.0.jar:2.50.0]
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadDownloadedResponses(WebClient.java:2493) ~[htmlunit-2.50.0.jar:2.50.0]
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.doProcessPostponedActions(JavaScriptEngine.java:977) ~[htmlunit-2.50.0.jar:2.50.0]
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:944) ~[htmlunit-2.50.0.jar:2.50.0]
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:598) ~[htmlunit-core-js-2.50.0.jar:na]
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:487) ~[htmlunit-core-js-2.50.0.jar:na]
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.callSecured(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:353) ~[htmlunit-2.50.0.jar:2.50.0]
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:829) ~[htmlunit-2.50.0.jar:2.50.0]
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:805) ~[htmlunit-2.50.0.jar:2.50.0]
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:111) ~[htmlunit-2.50.0.jar:2.50.0]
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.loadExternalJavaScriptFile(HtmlPage.java:1022) ~[htmlunit-2.50.0.jar:2.50.0]
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.ScriptElementSupport.executeScriptIfNeeded(ScriptElementSupport.java:196) ~[htmlunit-2.50.0.jar:2.50.0]
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.ScriptElementSupport$1.execute(ScriptElementSupport.java:120) ~[htmlunit-2.50.0.jar:2.50.0]
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.ScriptElementSupport.onAllChildrenAddedToPage(ScriptElementSupport.java:143) ~[htmlunit-2.50.0.jar:2.50.0]
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.onAllChildrenAddedToPage(HtmlScript.java:191) ~[htmlunit-2.50.0.jar:2.50.0]
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.parser.neko.HtmlUnitNekoDOMBuilder.endElement(HtmlUnitNekoDOMBuilder.java:551) ~[htmlunit-2.50.0.jar:2.50.0]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.12.0.jar:na]
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.parser.neko.HtmlUnitNekoDOMBuilder.endElement(HtmlUnitNekoDOMBuilder.java:503) ~[htmlunit-2.50.0.jar:2.50.0]
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLTagBalancer.callEndElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1216) ~[neko-htmlunit-2.50.0.jar:2.50.0]
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLTagBalancer.endElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1156) ~[neko-htmlunit-2.50.0.jar:2.50.0]
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.filters.DefaultFilter.endElement(DefaultFilter.java:219) ~[neko-htmlunit-2.50.0.jar:2.50.0]
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.filters.NamespaceBinder.endElement(NamespaceBinder.java:312) ~[neko-htmlunit-2.50.0.jar:2.50.0]
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scanEndElement(HTMLScanner.java:3189) ~[neko-htmlunit-2.50.0.jar:2.50.0]
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scan(HTMLScanner.java:2114) ~[neko-htmlunit-2.50.0.jar:2.50.0]
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner.scanDocument(HTMLScanner.java:937) ~[neko-htmlunit-2.50.0.jar:2.50.0]
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:443) ~[neko-htmlunit-2.50.0.jar:2.50.0]
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:394) ~[neko-htmlunit-2.50.0.jar:2.50.0]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.12.0.jar:na]
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.parser.neko.HtmlUnitNekoDOMBuilder.parse(HtmlUnitNekoDOMBuilder.java:751) ~[htmlunit-2.50.0.jar:2.50.0]
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.parser.neko.HtmlUnitNekoHtmlParser.parse(HtmlUnitNekoHtmlParser.java:208) ~[htmlunit-2.50.0.jar:2.50.0]
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createHtmlPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:296) ~[htmlunit-2.50.0.jar:2.50.0]
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:216) ~[htmlunit-2.50.0.jar:2.50.0]
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:682) ~[htmlunit-2.50.0.jar:2.50.0]
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:584) ~[htmlunit-2.50.0.jar:2.50.0]
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:499) ~[htmlunit-2.50.0.jar:2.50.0]
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:411) ~[htmlunit-2.50.0.jar:2.50.0]
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:546) ~[htmlunit-2.50.0.jar:2.50.0]
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:527) ~[htmlunit-2.50.0.jar:2.50.0]
    at de.toniritter.controller.FlashScraperController.startScraping(FlashScraperController.java:68) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1063) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:228) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1723) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
Caused by: net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot find function entries in object function Object() { [native code] }. (script in https://www.flashscore.com/unsupported/ from (31, 9) to (53, 10)#35)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:4527) ~[htmlunit-core-js-2.50.0.jar:na]
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:4508) ~[htmlunit-core-js-2.50.0.jar:na]
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:4540) ~[htmlunit-core-js-2.50.0.jar:na]
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeErrorById(ScriptRuntime.java:4545) ~[htmlunit-core-js-2.50.0.jar:na]
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.notFunctionError(ScriptRuntime.java:4624) ~[htmlunit-core-js-2.50.0.jar:na]
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThisHelper(ScriptRuntime.java:2570) ~[htmlunit-core-js-2.50.0.jar:na]
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThis(ScriptRuntime.java:2553) ~[htmlunit-core-js-2.50.0.jar:na]
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1663) ~[htmlunit-core-js-2.50.0.jar:na]
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:1053) ~[htmlunit-core-js-2.50.0.jar:na]
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:111) ~[htmlunit-core-js-2.50.0.jar:na]
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:395) ~[htmlunit-core-js-2.50.0.jar:na]
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.doTopCall(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:339) ~[htmlunit-2.50.0.jar:2.50.0]
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3852) ~[htmlunit-core-js-2.50.0.jar:na]
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.exec(InterpretedFunction.java:123) ~[htmlunit-core-js-2.50.0.jar:na]
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$2.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:820) ~[htmlunit-2.50.0.jar:2.50.0]
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:934) ~[htmlunit-2.50.0.jar:2.50.0]
    ... 118 common frames omitted

2021-07-06 08:46:17.757  INFO 14464 --- [Client@49a9c8bb] c.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebConsole   : *** cookie 'fonce_current_user' set (all pages): _ls_tracking=db75abda-de25-11eb-bb62-5e9401b680a6; _ga_3NV6GD9ZTT=GS1.1.1625553977.1.0.1625553977.60; _ga_HRK2668K68=GS1.1.1625553977.1.0.1625553977.0; _ga=GA1.1.1320121497.1625553977; fonce_current_session=0; fonce_current_day=0,2021-07-06; fonce_current_user=0
[]
```

Comment: i also tried, what is mentioned before from you @RBRi here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62465247/10579093 but this won't help anyway. I got same error message

Answer (score 0):

This code works here without the exception - i guess you do not use the latest version.

```
    String url = "https://flashScore.com";

    try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.BEST_SUPPORTED)) {
        HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(url);
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(3_000);

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("----------------");
        System.out.println(page.asNormalizedText());
        System.out.println("----------------");
    }
```

But i end up on this page

```
----------------
FlashScore.com
We can´t display the page, because your browser doesn´t support the required functions.
If you want to visit the lite version of our website, tap on the following link.
Go to www.flashscore.mobi
You can also download one of the modern browsers:
Chrome | Firefox | Edge
----------------
```

I have no idea about the browser check the page does. Maybe you can use this sample code and have al look on the network traffic (using Charles or Fiddler) to get an idea what is wrong. Or maybe the check is done in plain javascript on the client. If you think you found the reason feel free to open an issue at github and i will try to make HtmlUnit more compatible.

Comment: Looks like this https://www.flashscore.com/x/js/browsercompatibility_4.js script does the check and the redirect.

Comment: Hey, i use the version 2.50.0 and issue #368 is created on github :) thx